# Dispaying certain strings of a text file in command console using code written in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've faced with a kinda specific problem. My goal is to emplement input of name and number of a person using **\w**  as the 1st parament and Name as the 2nd and number as the 3rd ;
And **\r** parament as the 1st parament to find and display on screen the number of a person whose name I have just entered as a the 2nd parametr after **\r**.
My batch file name is database.bat
So for example when I enter
`database \w Peter.Parker +79342342`
textfile accepts it perfectly

But when I want to get the number of Peter.Parker entering

```
database  \r Peter.Parker
```

it does not work out.
The main code

```
@echo off
set "BUILDMODE=%1"
set "FIO=%2"
if "%BUILDMODE%"=="\w" (
    echo %2 >>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\in.txt"^
    echo %3 >>"C:\Users\user\Desktop\in.txt"
)

if "%BUILDMODE%" == "\r" (
set A 
set B
set C
@echo off
 for /f "tokens=2,3" %%A in ("C:\Users\user\Desktop\in.txt") do ( if "%%A"=="%FIO%" (echo %B%))
```

Could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are outputting the word **echo** to your `in.txt` file.

Comment: Oh, maybe. But I have recently got that it is likely that "if" stucture is not allowed inside "for" loop. So can't you advise how to better organize my code and make it valid?

Comment: Your tokens are set to 2 and 3.  But the name is token 1. And you need to use the `USEBACKQ` option.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, my bad:) but unfortunately it does not change the concept of the problem. What do you think intercepts? P.S. I have fixed the problem with tokens but it didn;t help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comments above. Your code was echoing the word echo to your output.  Also you were not using the correct tokens and you also need to use the USEBACKQ option because the path to the file name is quoted.  You are also echoing the %%B variable incorrectly.  You have it as %B%.  I personally would not use back slashes for option.  The standard for pretty much all applications is to use forward slashes (/r /w).

Regardless here is your code fixed and tested.

```
@echo off
set "BUILDMODE=%1"
set "FIO=%2"
if "%BUILDMODE%"=="\w" (
    >>"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\in.txt" echo %2 %3
)

if "%BUILDMODE%"=="\r" (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims= " %%A in ("C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\in.txt") do (
        if "%%A"=="%FIO%" echo %%B
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all remarks and the answer. They were very helpful!